# Відмінювання прізвищ із закінченням "ко"

Tags: граматика, orthography, власні-назви

Досить часто стикаюсь з такою ситуацією: в усному спілкуванні, в документах моє прізвище відмінюють. Хоча, наскільки я пам'ятаю зі шкільного курсу української мови та з університету, чоловічі прізвища, ща мають закінчення "ко" не відміняються. Наприклад, Стецько, Гречко, Бондаренко. При розмові люди кажуть: я дав грошей Стецьку/Бондаренку. Так само й пишуть в документах: видано Стецьку/Бондаренку. Чи то є правильним вживанням прізвищ в українській мові, чи то я щось плутаю? Всім дякую за відповідь

Comment: У мене прізвище Побочій як в жіночому роді вірно.

Comment: @Роман раджу вам зробити окреме запитання з поясненням, що саме вам незрозуміло. Варто також написати, де ви шукали відповідь самостійно.

Comment: Якщо коротко, то українською такі прізвища відмінюють, коли носій чоловік (_нема Тараса Петренка_), і не відмінюють, коли носій жінка (_нема Оксани Петренко_). А російською — не відмінюють для обох родів. Я припускаю, Ви сплутали з правилами для жіночого роду або з правилами російської мови, або Ваш викладач помилився.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Згідно з [чинним правописом](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil4.htm#par102), відмінюються:

IV.§102.1. Українські та інші слов’янські прізвища, що мають закінчення іменників I відміни, відмінюються як відповідні іменники I відміни, а прізвища із закінченнями іменників II відміни відмінюються за зразками відмінювання відповідних іменників II відміни:

(з прикладів):

Симоненко — Симоненка, Симоненкові (Симоненку) й т. д.

Але!

IV.§102.4. Жіночі прізвища на приголосний та о не відмінюються: Марії Сеник, Надії Балій, з Ніною Байко. Аналогічні чоловічі прізвища відмінюються як відповідні іменники: Василя Сеника, Михайлові Балієві, з Андрієм Байком.

Answer (score 8):

Українські та інші слов'янські прізвища, що мають закінчення І відміни, відмінюються як відповідні іменники І відміни, а прізвища із закінченнями ІІ відміни - за зразком відмінювання іменників ІІ відміни. **Жіночі** прізвища на приголосний та -о не відмінюються.

[Джерело](http://www.linguist.univ.kiev.ua/WINS/pidruchn/imen/ilona2.htm#P_SIX)

Answer (score 7):

Є доволі прості [правила](http://www.linguist.univ.kiev.ua/WINS/pidruchn/imen/ilona2.htm#P_SIX).

1. Українські та інші слов'янські прізвища, що мають закінчення І відміни, відмінюються як [відповідні іменники](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil4.htm).
2. Прізвища із закінченнями ІІ відміни — як іменники ІІ відміни.
3. Жіночі прізвища на приголосний та -о [не відмінюються](http://studopedia.org/12-91886.html).
4. [Не відмінюються](http://labook.com.ua/book_stilistika-dilovo-movi_672/24_-21.-vdmnyuvannya-przvishh) псевдоніми і слов'янські прізвища на е, і (Ле, Трублаїні, Леле), а також прізвища іншомовного походження на і, е, у, о, наголошені а, я та інші нетипові для української мови закінчення (Беранже, Гете, Руставелі, Петефі, Ло-тяну, Шоу, Бокаччо, Гюго).

Answer (score 3):

Цей допис **не є чистою відповіддю**, хоча частково можна вважати, бо деякі згадують про **незмінність чоловічих прізвишч** *у давнину*

Не знаю про яку саму давнину кажуть, [почну](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/119/585) з новітніх часів

[2012](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil4.htm#par102) § 102
[2007](https://www.college-chnu.cv.ua/images/Books/pravopys.pdf)
[2003](http://litopys.org.ua/pdf/proekt_2003.pdf) § 105
[2000](http://flightcollege.com.ua/library/8%20%D0%A4%D0%98%D0%9B%D0%9E%D0%9B%D0%9E%D0%93%D0%98%D0%A7%D0%95%D0%A1%D0%9A%D0%98%D0%95%20%D0%9D%D0%90%D0%A3%D0%9A%D0%98/81%20%D0%AF%D0%97%D0%AB%D0%9A%D0%9E%D0%97%D0%9D%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%95/81.2%20%D0%A3%D0%9A%D0%A0/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%81%202007.djvu)
[1994](http://flightcollege.com.ua/library/8%20%D0%A4%D0%98%D0%9B%D0%9E%D0%9B%D0%9E%D0%93%D0%98%D0%A7%D0%95%D0%A1%D0%9A%D0%98%D0%95%20%D0%9D%D0%90%D0%A3%D0%9A%D0%98/81%20%D0%AF%D0%97%D0%AB%D0%9A%D0%9E%D0%97%D0%9D%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%95/81.2%20%D0%A3%D0%9A%D0%A0/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%81%201994.djvu)

Є шче [1993](http://google.com/books?id=WKzqAAAAMAAJ), але я його дістати не можу

> 1. Українські та інші слов’янські прізвища, що мають закінчення іменників I відміни, відмінюються як відповідні іменники I відміни, а прізвища із закінченнями іменників II відміни відмінюються за зразками відмінювання відповідних іменників II відміни:
>
> *Симоненко — Симоненка, Симоненкові (Симоненку) й т. д.*

Вже якнайменше 23 роки вільної України пройшло, а люди *не перевчилися*

---

Але нумо продовжувати — правописи спочатку невільної України

[1986](https://toloka.to/t47871) сторінки 492—483 [Головашчука](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%89%D1%83%D0%BA_%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%86%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)

> Іменники 2 відміни (**чоловічого роду** з кінцевим приголосним та *-й* або із закінченням **-о**, середнього із закінченнями *-о, -е, -я*, крім іменників, в яких при відмінюванні зʼявляються суфікси *-ат- (-ят), -ен-*) мають в однині такі відмінкові закінчення:
>
> У **родовому відмінку** […] закінчення **-а** у твердій та мішаній групах […] мають іменники чоловічого роду, що означають: а) назви осіб, власні імена, **прізвища** й прізвиська, а також персоніфіковані предмети та явища

[1940](http://lib.movahistory.org.ua/PRAWOPYS/UP_40_p.djvu) § 47
[1938](http://lib.movahistory.org.ua/PRAWOPYS/UP_38_p.djvu)

> **У родовому відмінку однини іменники другої відміни** мають закінчення *-а, -я, у-, -ю*.
>
> 1. *-а, -я* мають:
>
>    2. Іменники чол. р. цієї відміни (в твердій і мішаній групах -а, в мʼякій -я), коли вони означають
>
>       - Людей, зокрема власні імена і **прізвища**

[1933](http://lib.movahistory.org.ua/PRAWOPYS/UP_33.djvu) § 22—23
Тут чомусь звичні нам перші дві відміни записані навпаки, але правила зміну чоловічого прізвишча *залишене*

По суті, **все так само**, як і пізніше; хіба у давальному відмінку *рекомендували* вживати ріжні форми закінчень *-у*, *-ові* при збігу слів

Доходимо до вельми похилого віку, коли правопис був знов штибу вільним і після якого дійсно тре було *перевчитися*

[1928](https://r2u.org.ua/node/247) § 78

> Усі інші українські прізвища відмінюються як звичайні слова; прикметникові — як прикметники, іменникові — як іменники, напр.: *Іван Лободюченко, Івана Лободюченк**а**, з Іваном Лободюченк**ом**, Іванові Петровичеві (Петровичу) Лободюченк**ові*** і т. ін.

Також стає зрозуміло відки майбутня таблиця відмін: [§ 23](https://r2u.org.ua/node/229)

І тут але: **все так само**!

---

Після прогляду маю дві цікаві речі, які я би хтів знати у коментарях до мого допису

**Перша:** чому змінили колонки таблиці (але на це не тре відповідати)?

**Друга:** **по чому** ті люди вчилися?

> [Andrew](/users/79/andrew) Хоча, наскільки я пам'ятаю зі шкільного курсу української мови та з університету, чоловічі прізвища, ща мають закінчення "ко" не відміняються.
>
> [user1417](/users/1417/user1417) Можливо зараз і такий правопис,але коли я також навчалася, не було відмінювання прізвищ із закінченням -ко.Відмінювалися лише імена і по батькові